# ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm having the following error when trying to save an entry with the same URL and user_id. The issue here is that I need to add it but with a different provider (Yext, Synup or Default) (look at the very end of the ActiveRecordError).

Below, I pasted the validations in my controller and the table indexes as well but I'm not sure if

1) I need to remove the current index and add a new one with the **provider** column

AND/OR

2) change the validates in the controller to allow saving the records with same **user_id, url but different provider**

**Thanks for your answer!!**

ActiveRecord Error:

```
#<ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '1070078-https://www.cylex.ca/company/the-painted-window-wedding-' for key 'index_business_profiles_on_user_id_and_url': INSERT INTO `business_profiles` (`local_seo_site_id`, `url`, `success_at`, `company_location_id`, `provider`, `user_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (136, 'https://www.cylex.ca/company/the-painted-window-wedding-venue-24052526.html', '2019-06-08 07:36:36', 1051892, 'synup', 1070078, '2019-06-08 07:36:36', '2019-06-08 07:36:36')>
```

Validations:

```
validates :user_id, :local_seo_site_id, :url, presence: true
  validates_uniqueness_of :url, scope: [:user_id, :provider], case_sensitive: false, if: :url_changed?
  # vendor can't add same directory twice to same account
  validates_uniqueness_of :local_seo_site_id, scope: [:user_id, :admin_id, :company_location_id], on: :create, if: :added_by_vendor?
  validates :url, :url => true, if: :url_changed?
```

Table Index:

```
add_index :business_profiles, [:user_id, :url], unique: true
```

Comment: The first option, just remove current index and create another one. The second option I think will NOT work for this case

Answer (score 1):

the controller validation enforces a unique triplet (url,user_id,provider),
while the index enforces a unique pair (user_id,url).

if you want to create a record with the same user_id and url than an existing record, but with another provider, removing the current unique index from the database and adding a new unique index for triplet should do the trick.

`add_index :business_profiles, [:user_id, :url, :provider], unique: true`